# Asynchronous POST shows Unexpected token n

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am posting data via `jQuery` `$.ajax()` call like so:

```
var data = {};
data.name = $("#name").val();
data.email = $("#email").val();
data.message = $("#message").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://myHost/contact/sendEmail",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json", 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
         console.log("success");
    }
});
```

Which is then getting routed by `contactRoutes.js`:

```
contactRouter.route("/sendEmail").post(contactController.sendEmail);
```

To a controller which is supposed to pull the body of the request to then make an API call and send the email message.

sendEmail:

```
var sendEmail = function(req, res) {
    var payload = {
        to: req.body.email,
        from: "noReply@test.com",
        subject: req.body.name,
        text: req.body.message
    };
    ...Omitted for brevity
};
```

The error I continue to receive is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token n` in the `body-parser` module. I have `app.js` setup like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

I'm lost as to where to look. I've examined my `JSON` object and it *appears* correct, but obviously I'm missing something. Anyone have any suggestions? Also, how can I be sure that `contactRoutes.js` is picking up the content passed in `data`?

Comment: Could a NaN somehow make its way in your JSON ?

Comment: Have you tried `data: JSON.stringify(data),`?

Comment: @Slytherin That's what I'm trying to figure out, but don't see where that is possible since I am manually setting the `JSON` object's properties.

Comment: @Satpal Yes, I did. Unfortunately, that hasn't resolved my problem either :(

Comment: @user2596756 The error you mentioned is because jQuery will format a `data` object as URL-encoded (`name=Your%20Name&email=...`), while you've specified `contentType: "application/json"`. Satpal's suggestion of `data: JSON.stringify(data)` should resolve at least that error. You can also remove the `contentType` option and continue using `data: data`, letting jQuery determine the format and header – `bodyParser.urlencoded()` will be able to parse it.